# Javascript - Append character and replace together

Tags: javascript, url, replace, append

Please help me to achieve the below

Ex: 
http://www.something.com is my text in a textbox "txtSource"

I want to replace the above "http://www.something.com" with 
http://nothing.nothing.something.com
where, **www.** should be ommitted and "**nothing.nothing**" should be added for whatever url I mention in the txtSource.

In other way, Its just a matter of replacing **www.** with **nothing.nothing**
Please help me to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you're certain that the URL is all that will be there in the textbox, you can do this with something as simple as this:

```
var box = document.getElementById('txtSource');
box.textContent = box.textContent.replace('www', 'nothing.nothing');
```

The 'www' could be a Regular Expression instead, but since you're just searching for one instance of 'www' you can use what I've shown above. You may want to add the case-insensitive modifier so it'll replace URLs like `http://wWw.something.com` as well. To do that, you'd use this:

```
box.textContent = box.textContent.replace(/www/i, 'nothing.nothing');
```

Read more about Regular Expressions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8Vjyr/1)

Comment: Pls see the fiddle updated and let me know how to get the output.http://jsfiddle.net/8Vjyr/2/

Answer (score 0):

assuming you mean input by text box:

```
var input = document.getElementById('txtSource');
input.value = input.value.replace(/www/i, 'nothing.nothing');
```

Comment: There are a few things you should do to make it work: 1. correct the HTML markup, 2. wrap `txtSource` in quotes in javascript, 3. add code to change the content of `txtDest`. You can see the fixed version of your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8Vjyr/3/

Comment: Any idea how to open the generated new url in new tab of browser while clicking on "Click" button ? could you please update the fiddle . Thanks in adcance

Comment: `URL` opening behavior shouldn't be changed, it's kinda a user preference, however `window.open(url, '_newTab')` may work in some browsers (Tested and worked in `Firefox`, didn't work in `Safari`, should work in `Chrome`, not sure about `IE`). Updated fiddle: `http://jsfiddle.net/8Vjyr/4/`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Can we open both the Source and Destination URL's in different tabs ?

Comment: Maybe you can do this in some browsers but generally `_newtab` is the name of the window you want to open and if you open two windows with same name, the content will be overrided.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the javascript function for strings [.replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) like this:

```
var str='http://www.something.com';

var newstr = str.replace(/www/i,'nothing.nothing');
```

What you are doing here is to provide a regular expression that matches what you want to replace and the string to replace it. The '/' of the /www/i acts as an indicator of the beginning and the end of the regular expression, and the 'i' makes it case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about replacing strings, then never use web link formats ('www.exam...') It would be like using measurements of distance to describe time (see 'parsecs').

If you are indeed talking about changing the actual website shown in the web browser, then you can use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to redirect web links.

The user would enter

```
www.example.com/index.html
```

and `mod_rewrite` would display it as

```
www.example.com
```